# Azure Synapse Sparkpool 0 core limit

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I want to use a Spark pool in Synapse, but for every notebook execution fails with the following error:

```
InvalidHttpRequestToLivy: Your Spark job requested 24 vcores. 
However, the workspace has a 0 core limit. 
Try reducing the numbers of vcores requested or increasing your vcore quota. 
HTTP status code: 400.
```

A simple print statement gives me the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: No, how can I see how much vcores my workspace has?

Comment: You can request quota on given link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket